# Resize images, keep ratio, with size constraints

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I have a bunch of images in a folder with different dimensions and ratio.

I want to shrink all of them while keeping a minimum height and width, while keeping the same ratio.

Something like:
`convert  -resize -minwidth 300 -minheight 200 -keep-ratio src *.jpg`

Then all shrinked images would have at least 300 width and 200 height, and they will retain the original ratio.

Is this even possible without some heavy scripting?

Things I've tried:

```
➜  swazidowners mogrify -resize 300x200^ "*.jpg"
zsh: no matches found: 300x200^
➜  swazidowners mogrify -resize 300x200^ bbq.jpg
zsh: no matches found: 300x200^
➜  swazidowners mogrify -resize 300x200 bbq.jpg # just to show that it works without ^ character
➜  swazidowners
```

System info:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04x64

```
$ mogrify -version  
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
mogrify -resize '300x200^' *.jpg
```

make sure you run this on a copy of your images as it replaces them.

Comment: I'm getting `zsh: no matches found: 300x200^`

Comment: normally you would get this message if there are no files found that match *.jpg, but I assume you have right?

Comment: yup, I have and I tested multiple time :( Does that work for u?

Comment: yes, using ubuntu 16.04 and imagemagick (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3)

Comment: could you try to use quotes: mogrify -resize 300x200^ "*.jpg"

Comment: Tried that. Edited the questions with the output

Comment: thanks. what's the version of imagemagick (execute mogrify -version) you're using? the ^ is supported from v6.3.8-3 and upwards.

Comment: same version I'm using :). I'm not familiar with this 'zsh'. Maybe the ^ has a special meaning. Can you try to put also that part in quotes: mogrify -resize "300x200^" "*.jpg

Comment: @AdamGoldman: Your shell is interpreting a mogrify parameter as a pattern to match. See my edit to the answer which puts the parameter in quotes so that zsh doesn't try any funny stuff with it.

Comment: works! u guys are awesome :)